# Page Viewer Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-viewer-web-part

From today we are having an weird issue in one of our share point portal .We have a html page with form actions and this page is referenced in our portal through a Page viewer web part and from today even though the whole portal is loading its  not loading the page viewer web part and once the page loads if i do a refresh on the browser and then the web part started to appear

Can some one please suggest me whats happening

Thanks

Comment: How does the html page behave if you hit it directly, outside of the Page Viewer Web Part? Could it be that the server hosting that page was performance issues at the time?

Comment: Hi rob i am able to access the page outside the page viewer web part without any problem..Also its a html page kept in a SharePoint document library